# Binary Search Map which hashes values

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, treemap

The following code provides a simple version of a class which tracks how often a string was inputed (method addPV) and can output the k strings with the highest count in order (method firstK).

In the simplified code below, Binary Seach Tree (treeset) is used to track the counts and keep the order. A secondary data structure (hashmap) is used to rapidly access the elements in treeset. A composite entry class containing the string name and count is used, where the count determines the natural order and the name the hashCode.

The most elegant way would be to use a **BST (e.g. treemap) whose entry would have the count as a key and the string name as a value. An internal hashmap could be used to efficiently access entries in the BST in constant time. Is there a standard data structure in common libraries to do that for general objects?**

```
import java.util.*;

public class MostVisitedPages {
    private HashMap<String,CountEntry> hm = new HashMap<>();
    private TreeSet<CountEntry> ts = new TreeSet<>();

    private static class CountEntry implements Comparable<CountEntry>{
        String page;
        int count;

        CountEntry (String page, int count){
            this.page = page;
            this.count = count;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(CountEntry entry){
            int res = Integer.compare(count,entry.count);
            return res != 0 ? res: page.compareTo(entry.page);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj){
            if(this == obj) return true;
            else if (obj==null || !(obj instanceof CountEntry)) return false;
            else {return page.equals(((CountEntry)obj).page);}
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode(){
            return page.hashCode();
        }
    }

    public void addPV(String p){
        if(hm.containsKey(p)){
            CountEntry ce = hm.get(p);
            ts.remove(ce);
            ce.count += 1;
            ts.add(ce);
        } else {
            CountEntry ce = new CountEntry(p,1);
            ts.add(ce);
            hm.put(p, ce);
        }
    }

    public List<String> firstK(int k){
        List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>(k);

        Iterator<CountEntry> it = ts.descendingIterator();
        for(int i = 0; i<k && i<hm.size(); i++){
            ret.add(it.next().page);
        }

        return ret;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a `TreeMap` class [in JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

It should fit your needs.

Comment: No, TreeMap does not hash the values. containsValue(...) of TreeMap thus has linear running time.